# Conservative force definition

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, definition, conservative-field

[Classical Mechanics, by John Taylor](https://books.google.com/books/about/Classical_Mechanics.html?id=P1kCtNr-pJsC) defines a conservative force $F$ as a force that satisfies:

> 1. $F$ depends only on the particle's position and no other variables.
> 2. Work done by $F$ is the same for all paths taken between two points

I'm wondering if this definition is redundant. Doesn't (1) imply (2) and vice versa?

If not, what is an example of a force that satisfies (1) but not (2) and an example of a force that satisfies (2) but not (1)?

Comment: What if the force is dependent only on the particle's position and on time?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/601814/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment of @probably_someone shows clearly the necessity of (1). It  eliminates a possible force dependence on time, velocity or on any other parameters.

(2) does not follow from (1): Consider the force on one pole of a long thin bar magnet which is next to a current carrying wire. The work done moving it in a circle around the wire is different to the work done in a loop which doesn't go around the wire. The same would be the location dependent force on an object moved in a water whirl.

(1) doesn't follow from (2): When a charged particle moves in a magnetic field no work is done on the particle on going on any path from A to B. The force experienced by the particle is dependent on the velocity not only the position (inhomogeneous B).