# Conditions for a force to be conservative

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, work, definition, conservative-field

Taylor's classical mechanics ,chapter 4, states:

A force is conservative,**if and only if** it satisfies two conditions:

1. $\vec{F}$ is a function of **only** the position. i.e $\vec{F}=\vec{F}(\vec{r})$.
2. The work done by the force is independent of the path between two points.

**Questions:**

- **Doesn't $1$ automatically imply $2$?** : Since from 1, we can conclude that $\vec{F}=f(r)\hat{r}$, for some function $f$. Then, if $A$ is the antiderivative of $f$, we can say that $\vec{F}=\nabla{A}$, and therefore the work (line integral) will depend on the  final and initial positions only.  Or even simply put, $\vec{F}.d\vec{r}$ is a simple function of $r$ alone, so the integral will only depend on initial and final $r$.
- I have seen in many places, only "2" is the definition of a conservative force. In light of this, I cant think of why 1 *has* to be true: i.e how is it necessary that path independence implies $\vec{F}=f(r)\hat{r}$.

It could be that my interpretation of 1 as $\vec{F}=f(r)\hat{r}$ is wrong, on which my entire question hinges. Taylor writes $\vec{F}=\vec{F(\vec{r})}$ , which I interpreted as : "since F is a function of position *vector*, F is a function of *both* the magnitude and direction, and hence $\vec{F}=f(r)\hat{r}$".

Comment: Does this help: https://tok.fandom.com/wiki/Central_force

Comment: A function of the position only has not to be a radial function (central force). A simple counterexample is the 2D harmonic oscillator with two different force constants. It is a conservative but  a non-central force.

Comment: 1 means that it isnt a function of time. It doesnt change (unless the distances change)

Comment: Mathematically the curl of the gradient of any scalar potential is always zero.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your conclusions are not correct.
Here is a simple counter-example.
Consider this force
$$\vec{F}=k(x\hat{y}-y\hat{x})$$
where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are the unit-vectors
in $x$ and $y$-direction, and $k$ is some constant.

From this definition we see, the magnitude
of the force is $F=k\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=kr$,
and its direction is at right angle to
$\vec{r}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}$.
So we can visualize this force field like this:
[image]
The force circulates the origin in a counter-clockwise sense.

This force clearly satifies your first condition

> 1. $\vec{F}$ is a function of **only** the position,
>    i.e. $\vec{F}=\vec{F}(\vec{r})$

But it is not of the form $\vec{F}=f(r)\hat{r}$.

And this force violates your second condition

> 2. The work done by the force is independent of the
>    path between the two point.

To prove this consider the following two paths:

- Path A (in green): beginning on the right
  at $(x=R,y=0)$, doing a half circle counterclockwise,
  to the point on the left $(x=-R,y=0)$.
- Path B (in red): beginning on the right
  at $(x=R,y=0)$, doing a half circle clockwise,
  to the point on the left $(x=-R,y=0)$.

[image]

Then the work for path A is (because here $\vec{F}$ is always parallel to $d\vec{r}$)
$$W_A=\int \vec{F}(\vec{r}) d\vec{r}=kR\cdot\pi R=\pi k R^2.$$

Then the work for path B is (because here $\vec{F}$ is always antiparallel to $d\vec{r}$)
$$W_B=\int \vec{F}(\vec{r}) d\vec{r}=-kR\cdot\pi R=-\pi k R^2.$$

You see, the work is different for the two paths, although
the start and end point of the paths are the same.

This is a simple example of a non-[conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force#Mathematical_description).
The non-conservativeness can easily be checked
by calculating its [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Usage) and finding it is non-zero.

$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F}
 =\vec{\nabla}\times k(x\hat{y}-y\hat{x})
 =2k\hat{z}
 \ne \vec{0}$$

Comment: I know it's a bit late to ask but does the 2nd condition in op's question (in short, the curl being zero) implies the first condition( that $F$ is a function of position only)?

Comment: @GaurangAgrawal Yep I have the same question... Any answers?

Answer (score 2):

If the function is (as you assumed) one of distance, then you are right. But there are many functions of position coordinates whose curl is not zero, hence non-conservative.

**Edit:** Try for example $$F = (xy,-xy,0)$$

Answer (score 2):

The central forces with spherical symmetry are also conservative forces.
You can show this proving that the work does not depend on the path.
HP: $$\vec{F}=F(r)\vec{r}$$ where $\vec{r}$ is the unitary vector to the position vector.
So you have: $$W_{AB}=\int_A^BF(r)\vec{r}\cdot ds$$ Since in polar coordinates elementar displacement in $d\vec{s}=d\vec{r}=dr\vec{r}+rd\theta\vec{\theta}$, have $$W_{AB}=\int_{r_A}^{r_B}F(r)dr$$ So the work done by the force depends only by the initial and final distance.
You can also show that a central force with spherical symmetry is irrotational calculating the curl of the force but in polar coordinates.
Remember that the fact that the curl of the force is $0$ isn't enough for the conservation but the function must to be defined on a simply connetted domain, like gravitational and Coulomb force.