# Form of potential $V$ for conservative forces

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, definition, conservative-field

Goldstein, Pg 21,3rd E.d writes

> only if $V$ is not an explicit function of time is the system conservative

That means $V(r,\dot{r})$ is a conservative potential, however I think that only potentials of the form $V(r)$ are conservative potentials.

So what is the form of potential for conservative forces? Is there any consensus about it?

Comment: Doesn't $\dot{r}$ mean the same thing as $\frac{dr}{dt}$? So for one thing you'd have to define which position (the position of which object in your system) is changing with respect to time...and then you'd have a system where $V$ is an explicit function of time.

Comment: @ThePhoton That isn't explicit time dependence though. e.g. I can say $V(5\,\rm m,\,3\,\rm{m/s})=2\,\rm J$ with no reference to time. Just because $r$ and $\dot r$ depend on time for a given system doesn't make $V(r,\dot r)$ have explicit time dependence.

Comment: @BioPhysicist, If I say I have a potential function $V(r)$, then I am saying what the potential is at each point in space. If I have a potential function $V(r, \dot{r})$, then what does it mean? What position is moving and why would the potential function depend on it? What physical mechanism could lead to $V$ having a $\dot{r}$ dependence?

Comment: @ThePhoton I agree. That doesn't mean $V(r,\dot r)$ has explicit time dependence.

Comment: @BioPhysicist just hiding the time dependence behind another variable doesn't change the nature of the system. So either the definition of "explicit time dependence" has to change, or it's wrong to say that lack of explicit time dependence is sufficient to show the potential is conservative. Or it's simply not physical to have a potential function that depends on $\dot{r}$, and the question is moot.

Comment: @ThePhoton "hiding the dependence" is literally the difference between explicit and implicit dependence. It does change the nature of the system actually. e.g. $L(r,\dot r)$ is different than $L(r,\dot r,t)$. An electric field that varies with time is different than a field that is constant in time even if in both situations a charged particle's position is varying over time in the field.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/601814/2451 and links therein.